# SQL breaking a string between characters in a view

Tags: sql, select

I need some help with a SQL view please..

I am creating a view to be used for reporting via Crysyal.. One of the fields that I need is a string field that contains three values separated by a character '~' I basically need this splitting out within my Select query within view to three separate fields..

An example is below.. The field is called 'Problem.Description' and contains the following example data..

'Trading~Concession~Telemetry - OCPD / Low Sales'

So, in my sql view I get a single column.. What I need is three columns each with different column names containing the data between the '~'..

For example:

Trading Status         Problem1         Problem2
Trading                Concession       Telemetry - OCPD / Low Sales

I have a trawl around and found a few code examples that work but none will work within my view.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean split the string at the delimiter ?

```
declare @a as varchar(100)
set @a='Trading~Concession~Telemetry - OCPD / Low Sales'

select substring(@a,0,patindex('%~%',@a)) as trading_status,reverse(substring(reverse(@a),0,PATINDEX('%~%',(reverse(@a))))) as problem1,
substring(@a,patindex('%~%',@a)+1,10) as problem2
```

## [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17534)

Note:its not a dynamic solution but it works in your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(c1 as nvarchar) + '~' + cast(c2 as nvarchar) + '~' + cast(c3 as nvarchar)
from table
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the help .. The cast is just changing the columns C1 etc to Nvarchar.. In my report i need to split a single column into 3 columns between the delimiter.. I am playing around with TRIM but getting nowhere fast..

Comment: Hi, I put cast only for reason if you want to add columns that not nvarchar. For example - '1~bla~bla'. If c1 here would be int - you'll get an error without cast

Comment: But the OP is asking for the reverse direction. You are concatinating string and he wants a split.

Comment: Exactly, if we can do the reverse of the above.. i've cracked it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to build such a splitting operation with a combination of [SUBSTRING](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SUBSTRING) and [INSTR](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/INSTR).
Your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL-Server?) could provide more convenient functions too. Check the respective documentation for "string functions".

Comment: Thanks.. i'll have a search around with that term. Im using SQL Management Studio on SQL 2012.